# Debugging client side application

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug my client side code which i have checked-out from SVN to eclipse workspace. My server process is already up and running. I have a start-up script for our client which has the following line to start the client.

```
jre/bin/java splash:images/initializing.png -classpath "$CLASS_PATH" in.co.xxx.xxx.yyy.yyy.launcher.Launcher $* &
```

I added the debugging related arguments to it

```
jre/bin/java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=9045,suspend=n -splash:images/initializing.png -classpath "$CLASS_PATH" in.co.xxx.xxx.yyy.yyy.launcher.Launcher $* &
```

In Eclipse i went to debug configurations entered the hostname and port number(same i mentioned in the startup script (9045)). I added all the client related classes in source tab of debug configurations. Now comes the problem.

When i click debug button after all this, the remote debugger should be launching and waiting for the connection when i fire my start-up script. But it is saying

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused
```

I have tried with different port numbers as well. Nothing seems to work. Please suggest what am i missing here .

Comment: is there a firewall within the network?

Comment: In debug view check if the debug thread is already running, if yes terminate it.

Comment: there is no firewall in my network. Actually i am invoking the client process in the same machine where i have to code too. So should i be using host name as "localhost" ??

Comment: there is no debug thread already running. i checked

Comment: just try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: or try suspend=y and check whether the server process is waiting for a connection after startup

Comment: when i invoke my start-up script, user authentication page will appear. After the credentials are entered, my client application starts to load. So tried just now, if i click the debug button after the authentication page appears, the debugger launches but quickly terminates. So i put my break-point in one of the functionality of my application so that the debugger would stop the execution when i click that functionality button. But the debugger never launched again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Eclipse logs to see if anything further got logged there? Also, when you say debug did not launch 'post authentication page', did you see on the 'server side' if there is a message to 'standard output' stating that the debug port is 'released'? (something similar to this would be emitted on standard output). If this did not show up, then the 'first successful connection' might not have actually released the debugger while you think it did.

Also this works for me here, the only difference I see is that the order of parameters in your and my debug switch are different. Hope this helps!

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=n
```